# Send picture/video to TV via Linux

Tags: linux, dlna

My TV is DLNA-enabled.  On Windows 7, I can right click and play on my TV.

Is there such a thing for Linux?  Using FC.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a FC 12 tut:

- http://motersho.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/05/howto-configure-mediatombdlna-on-fedora-12-to-work-with-a-samsung-tv/

Also, take a look at DLNA software here:

- http://elinux.org/DLNA_Open_Source_Projects